# Java auto-boxing long and integer mistakes

Tags: java, android, autoboxing

When I cast 0 (zero) to Long or 0 (zero) to Integer, the device converts it to 0 directly as expected. After a while, the device starts boxing the 0 long value to 8 Long value and 0 int value to 2 Integer value. The device doing the same mistake while reading longs and integers from the database.

This problem started happening on the device "UBX V500S" with SafeDroid ROM, from china. The build information of the device is here:

```
BOARD=unknown
BOOTLOADER=unknown
BRAND=alps
CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a
CPU_ABI2=armeabi
DEVICE=vz6737t_66_a_n
DISPLAY=SQ31T_P1_00_XX_AU1616_U_R_181220_01
FINGERPRINT=alps/full_vz6737t_66_a_n/vz6737t_66_a_n:7.0/NRD90M/1545278007:user/dev-keys
HARDWARE=mt6735
HOST=u-r730-1
ID=SQ31T_P1_00_XX_AU1616_U_R_181220_01
IS_DEBUGGABLE=false
IS_EMULATOR=false
MANUFACTURER=UBX
MODEL=SQ31T
PERMISSIONS_REVIEW_REQUIRED=false
PRODUCT=full_vz6737t_66_a_n
PROJECT=SQ31T
PWV_CUSTOM_CUSTOM=XX
PWV_HAVE_SCANNER=false
RADIO=unknown
SERIAL=---
SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS=[armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS=[arm64-v8a]
SUPPORTED_ABIS=[0 = "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"]
TIME=1545277986000
TYPE=user
UNKNOWN=unknown
USER=Build
```

This is the result of the first launch:

```
(Long) 0L -> 0
```

[image: first launch]

This is the result when the device starts doing mistakes:

```
(Long) 0L -> 8
```

[image: boxing problem]

This is the result when the device starts doing mistakes:

```
(Integer) 0 -> 2
```

[image: boxing problem]

**Addition:**

While the device working properly when I checked the SQLite database cursor map values, they look correct. *"**id**" column indicates index 0, "**last_sycned_at**" column indicates 2*: 
[image: before_map_change]

When the device starts doing mistakes I also saw that the map values are changed, *"**id**" column indicates index 2, "**last_sycned_at**" column also indicates 2*: 
[image: after_map_change]

Comment: That looks like something is corrupting the cached values. As in, something has rewritten the instances of `Long`/`Integer` [stored in an array inside these classes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l780) to avoid having to create a new instance.